# npm install intermittently fails with Error: connect ETIMEDOUT in mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I installed node using Homebrew on my macbook. Since then, *npm install intermittently works*. Most of the times it fails with **stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT**

I am not behind any proxy. By looking at logs, its clear that npm is able to connect to its registry and even fetch couple of modules. But I haven't been able to figure out why the overall operation fails.

Any help will be really appreciated guys, I have already spent quite a some time on this.

```
Operating system : OSx Yosemite 10.10
```

**npm-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'karma' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
5 silly cache add args [ 'karma', null ]
6 verbose cache add spec karma
7 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'karma',
7 silly cache add   scope: null,
7 silly cache add   name: 'karma',
7 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
7 silly cache add   spec: '*',
7 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
8 verbose addNamed karma@*
9 silly addNamed semver.valid null
10 silly addNamed semver.validRange *
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'karma', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name karma
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
16 verbose addNameRange registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/karma not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:56:02
20 verbose request id b5cadf722d3efdbb
21 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
22 http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
23 silly get cb [ 200,
23 silly get   { server: 'CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)',
23 silly get     etag: '"DT9PQOT2U0ZYL04ALXLO8EZIB"',
23 silly get     'content-type': 'application/json',
23 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=60',
23 silly get     'content-length': '688276',
23 silly get     'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
23 silly get     date: 'Sun, 05 Apr 2015 04:25:58 GMT',
23 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
23 silly get     age: '0',
23 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
23 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-sn87-SIN',
23 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
23 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
23 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1428207957.998833,VS0,VE986',
23 silly get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
24 verbose get saving karma to /Users/lnagi/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/karma/.cache.json
25 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'karma', range: '*', hasData: true }
26 silly addNameRange versions [ 'karma',
26 silly addNameRange   [ '0.8.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.0-dart',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.2-dart',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.8.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.9.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.9',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.10',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.11',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.12',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.11-dev',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.9',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.12-dev',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.12-dev2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.13',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.11.14',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.10.10',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.1',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.3',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.4',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.5',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.6',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.6-beta-43e6e28',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.7',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.8',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.9',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.10',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.11',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.12',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.11-beta-3029418',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.13',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.14',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.15',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.16',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.16-beta-905422d',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.17',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.18',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.19',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.20',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.21',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.22',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.23',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.24',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.24-beta-6cf7955',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.25',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.25-beta-37a7958',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.25-beta-ad5bc24',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.26',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.27',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.28',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.28-beta-b9be580',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.29',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.30',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.31',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.28-beta-f65c864',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.24-dev-test',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.24-dev-socketio10',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.24-dev-socketio10-2',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.32-beta.0',
26 silly addNameRange     '0.12.32' ] ]
27 verbose addNamed karma@0.12.31
28 silly addNamed semver.valid 0.12.31
29 silly addNamed semver.validRange 0.12.31
30 silly mapToRegistry name karma
31 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
32 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
33 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/karma
34 verbose addRemoteTarball http://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.12.31.tgz not in flight; adding
35 verbose addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.12.31.tgz',
35 verbose addRemoteTarball   '806aa7c2acb13a39edb9374a7a477e643a5e94c9' ]
36 info retry fetch attempt 1 at 09:56:12
37 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:56:12
38 http fetch GET http://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.12.31.tgz
39 http fetch 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.12.31.tgz
40 silly fetchAndShaCheck shasum 806aa7c2acb13a39edb9374a7a477e643a5e94c9
41 verbose addTmpTarball /var/folders/9m/bs7p6nwx7yl0qnhqp5w56bds6jg4yr/T/npm-537-190af18b/registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-0.12.31.tgz not in flight; adding
42 verbose addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for karma@0.12.31
43 silly cache afterAdd karma@0.12.31
44 verbose afterAdd /Users/lnagi/.npm/karma/0.12.31/package/package.json not in flight; writing
45 verbose afterAdd /Users/lnagi/.npm/karma/0.12.31/package/package.json written


[ Truncating Logs ]


3157 info install sigmund@1.0.0
3158 info postinstall sigmund@1.0.0
3159 info preinstall lru-cache@2.5.0
3160 verbose unlock done using /Users/lnagi/.npm/_locks/sigmund-7e929465dc53e1e2.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/sigmund
3161 silly install resolved []
3162 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/lru-cache
3163 info build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/lru-cache
3164 verbose linkStuff [ true,
3164 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
3164 verbose linkStuff   false,
3164 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules' ]
3165 info linkStuff lru-cache@2.5.0
3166 verbose linkBins lru-cache@2.5.0
3167 verbose linkMans lru-cache@2.5.0
3168 verbose rebuildBundles lru-cache@2.5.0
3169 info install lru-cache@2.5.0
3170 info postinstall lru-cache@2.5.0
3171 verbose unlock done using /Users/lnagi/.npm/_locks/lru-cache-5118d5afb099be1e.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/lru-cache
3172 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch
3173 info build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch
3174 verbose linkStuff [ true,
3174 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
3174 verbose linkStuff   false,
3174 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules' ]
3175 info linkStuff minimatch@0.3.0
3176 verbose linkBins minimatch@0.3.0
3177 verbose linkMans minimatch@0.3.0
3178 verbose rebuildBundles minimatch@0.3.0
3179 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'lru-cache', 'sigmund' ]
3180 info install minimatch@0.3.0
3181 info postinstall minimatch@0.3.0
3182 verbose unlock done using /Users/lnagi/.npm/_locks/minimatch-d7c6cbc36211c07f.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch
3183 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob
3184 info build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob
3185 verbose linkStuff [ true,
3185 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
3185 verbose linkStuff   false,
3185 verbose linkStuff   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules' ]
3186 info linkStuff glob@3.2.11
3187 verbose linkBins glob@3.2.11
3188 verbose linkMans glob@3.2.11
3189 verbose rebuildBundles glob@3.2.11
3190 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'inherits', 'minimatch' ]
3191 info install glob@3.2.11
3192 info postinstall glob@3.2.11
3193 verbose unlock done using /Users/lnagi/.npm/_locks/glob-7bbc4b681e036c8e.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob
3194 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
3195 verbose unlock done using /Users/lnagi/.npm/_locks/karma-dbe64a2972f57692.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
3196 verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
3196 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
3196 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
3197 verbose cwd /Users/lnagi
3198 error Darwin 14.1.0
3199 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "karma"
3200 error node v0.12.2
3201 error npm  v2.7.4
3202 error code ETIMEDOUT
3203 error errno ETIMEDOUT
3204 error syscall connect
3205 error network connect ETIMEDOUT
3205 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
3205 error network and is related to network connectivity.
3205 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
3205 error network
3205 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
3205 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
3206 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
3207 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar
3208 info preuninstall chokidar@0.12.6
3209 info uninstall chokidar@0.12.6
3210 verbose unbuild rmStuff chokidar@0.12.6 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3211 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3212 info postuninstall chokidar@0.12.6
3213 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar is being purged from base /usr/local
3214 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar
3215 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar
3216 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3217 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/minimatch
3218 info preuninstall minimatch@0.2.14
3219 info uninstall minimatch@0.2.14
3220 verbose unbuild rmStuff minimatch@0.2.14 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3221 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3222 info postuninstall minimatch@0.2.14
3223 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/minimatch is being purged from base /usr/local
3224 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/minimatch
3225 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/minimatch
3226 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3227 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent
3228 info preuninstall useragent@2.0.10
3229 info uninstall useragent@2.0.10
3230 verbose unbuild rmStuff useragent@2.0.10 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3231 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3232 info postuninstall useragent@2.0.10
3233 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent is being purged from base /usr/local
3234 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent
3235 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent
3236 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3237 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io
3238 info preuninstall socket.io@0.9.16
3239 info uninstall socket.io@0.9.16
3240 verbose unbuild rmStuff socket.io@0.9.16 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3241 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3242 info postuninstall socket.io@0.9.16
3243 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io is being purged from base /usr/local
3244 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io
3245 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io
3246 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3247 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map
3248 info preuninstall source-map@0.1.43
3249 info uninstall source-map@0.1.43
3250 verbose unbuild rmStuff source-map@0.1.43 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3251 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3252 info postuninstall source-map@0.1.43
3253 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map is being purged from base /usr/local
3254 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map
3255 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map
3256 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3257 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy
3258 info preuninstall http-proxy@0.10.4
3259 info uninstall http-proxy@0.10.4
3260 verbose unbuild rmStuff http-proxy@0.10.4 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3261 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3262 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/.bin/node-http-proxy is being gently removed
3263 silly gentlyRm verifying /usr/local is an npm working directory
3264 silly gentlyRm containing path /usr/local is under npm's control, in /usr/local
3265 silly gentlyRm deletion target /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/.bin/node-http-proxy is under /usr/local
3266 verbose gentlyRm vacuuming from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/.bin/node-http-proxy up to /usr/local
3267 info postuninstall http-proxy@0.10.4
3268 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy is being purged from base /usr/local
3269 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy
3270 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy
3271 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3272 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect
3273 info preuninstall connect@2.26.6
3274 info uninstall connect@2.26.6
3275 verbose unbuild rmStuff connect@2.26.6 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3276 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3277 info postuninstall connect@2.26.6
3278 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect is being purged from base /usr/local
3279 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect
3280 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect
3281 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3282 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist
3283 info preuninstall optimist@0.6.1
3284 info uninstall optimist@0.6.1
3285 verbose unbuild rmStuff optimist@0.6.1 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3286 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3287 info postuninstall optimist@0.6.1
3288 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist is being purged from base /usr/local
3289 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist
3290 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist
3291 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3292 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/log4js
3293 info preuninstall log4js@0.6.22
3294 info uninstall log4js@0.6.22
3295 verbose unbuild rmStuff log4js@0.6.22 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3296 verbose unbuild rmStuff in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3297 info postuninstall log4js@0.6.22
3298 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/log4js is being purged from base /usr/local
3299 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/log4js
3300 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/log4js
3301 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules
3302 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/karma
3303 info preuninstall karma@0.12.31
3304 info uninstall karma@0.12.31
3305 verbose unbuild rmStuff karma@0.12.31 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
3306 info postuninstall karma@0.12.31
3307 silly gentlyRm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma is being purged from base /usr/local
3308 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
3309 silly vacuum-fs purging /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
3310 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: Why voted it down, is it not a valid question ?

Comment: I do have the same problem in Linux. It looks like re-installing npm is not enough